# Query in a batch takes from few millisec to 2 minutes on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-processing, database-deadlocks

I have a batch that loads configuration data parsed from about a hundred XLS workbooks, with information on cells position, type of cells, meaning of cells etc.

This is a very large batch, it involves use of several temporary tables,

Since it can start with an existing configuration, it need to merge the two configurations, so some temporary table are filled out-of-transaction, some are filled in-transaction.

On **Oracle 10g** the batch executes without any problem.

On **SQLServer 2008 R2** I'm experiencing some **random** hangs on 2-3 in-transaction `INSERT` queries.  This thing doesn't always happen, or maybe it happens on a query (that normally executes in few millisecs), but not on another on which it happened the time before.

I initially thought about a deadlock, **but raising query timeout to 3 minutes, it finally executes in about 2 minutes**. I repeat, these queries sometime executes in few millisecs.

I also specify that all queries are done with option for `ROWLOCK` only.

Monitoring SQL Server with profiler and activity monitor I don't see anything strange.
CPU is not hanged, there is memory, disk reads are about 0, disk writes are 0-200 kb/s not constant.

No one other is using this DB schema.

I really cannot work it out how to solve this.

**EDIT:**

This is ***one*** of the puzzling queries

```
INSERT INTO "LOAD"."META_CELLS_UOM" WITH (ROWLOCK) 
("UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOC_ID", "META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID") 

  SELECT "UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOC_ID", "META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID"
   FROM ( 
     SELECT "META_DOCUMENTS"."UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID", "META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_ROW" AS "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_COL" AS "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID"
     FROM "LOAD"."LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1"
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_DOCUMENTS" ON ("META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_CODE"="LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1"."META_DOC_CODE")
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_SECTIONS" ON ("META_SECTIONS"."META_DOC_ID"="META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID") AND ("META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_NAME"="LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1"."META_SECT_NAME")
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_SETS" ON ("META_SETS"."META_SECT_ID"="META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID") AND ("META_SETS"."META_DOC_ID"="META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID") AND ("META_SETS"."META_SET_NAME"="LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1"."META_SET_NAME")
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES" ON ("USER_DEF_ATTRIBUTES"."UDA_NAME"="LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1"."UDA_NAME")
     WHERE ("META_CELL_WUOM"=1)
     AND ("UDA_TYPE"='MATCH')
   ) "SELECTION"
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
     SELECT *
     FROM "LOAD"."META_CELLS_UOM"
     WHERE ("SELECTION"."META_SET_ID"="META_CELLS_UOM"."META_SET_ID")
     AND ("SELECTION"."UDA_ID"="META_CELLS_UOM"."UDA_ID")
  )
```

The destination table `META_CELLS_UOM` is empty, the source table `LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1` has about 80.000 records from which I select about 3000.

**EDIT 2:**

**There are no cuncurrent queries.** When the program hangs on the execution of above query this is a screenshot from SQL Server Mngmt Studio's Activity monitor:

[image]

Comment: How do you know there are random locks? Are you running any other processes at the same time? It cannot be a deadlock as deadlock is resolved immediately by killing one of the processes.

Comment: @Szymon I know that are *random* because it doesn't always hang on the same query, it sometimes doesn't hang at all. No other processes are running on that schema.

Comment: But how do you know they are actually locks? Have you checked the locks while the query is running? Or blocked processes?

Comment: Sorry, with **lock** I mean **query blocked for long time**. SQL profiler does not observe any DB lock nor DB deadlock. Also SQL Server Management Studio's Activity monitor shows that process as `RUNNING`.

Comment: I'm unclear about: what queries are running, are they running concurrently on multiple connections, locking/blocking information, execution plan(s). We need much more information to answer, because there is no obvious flaw visible. No useful answer can be given without more info.

Comment: @usr I've added some info, see edit. Unfortunately, I don't know any other info, if I did, I'd probably be not on SO.

Comment: @usr Please let me know if you want me to execute some particular command to gather more info.

Comment: Ok, no concurrent queries and apparently no activity on any resource. No blocking. Correct? I know of no normal reason this might be. I can only think of disk error (a hanging disk). Or some other process on the same server might be overloading the disk. But in that case, there should be wait info visible. Can you try looking into the error log? Also run DBCC CHECKDB.

Comment: It really sounds like some race condition. Even if you use row locks that insert can (maybe) cause table splits and this can cause page locks. Try to sniff what is being locked with sp_lock2.

Comment: @usr I also thought about a hanging disk, I will try on a VM. `CHECKDB` found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database `LOAD`, same for `MASTER`. How can I look into error log?

Comment: @jean *Sql profiler* does not observe any lock during the batch...

Comment: @Teejay in SSMS, Management -> SQL Server logs. Look for all errors, especially IO errors or anything indicating a hang.; Is there any way to reproduce the hang? By executing the query 1000s of times maybe?

Comment: @usr Found nothing interesting in logs. No errors at all.

Comment: @usr To reproduce the hang I need to execute the entire batch, because it relies on temporary tables created by the batch itself. When executing the batch I have about 50% probability of observing the hang.

Comment: @jean Using sp_lock2 i got a really large table of locks. More than 80k objects are involved so it is difficult to identify some relevant info. Suggestions?

Comment: @usr in the log i found some of this rows: `Autogrow of file 'LOAD_log' in database 'LOAD' took 116625 milliseconds.  Consider using ALTER DATABASE to set a smaller FILEGROWTH for this file.`.
Could it be related to the hang?

Comment: @Teejay I'd expect autogrow to show up as a wait type, but maybe I'm wrong with that. Turn off auto-shrink and disable any shrinking jobs. Presize the data and log files so that they have ample space to cover your transaction (for testing purposes, size them to a huge size). Find out whether you suffer from log fragmentation and fix it (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-transaction-log-fragmentation-a-primer/). Then, see whether the problem is gone. Autogrow can cause load and wait spikes. We don't want to see autogrow kick in in production.

Comment: @usr I currently wiped the log by setting recover mode to Simple and then shrinking the DB (hey it's a test DB!). See what happens!

Comment: @usr No way, hang remains

Comment: Do not shrink the DB, grow it! Is the database with the issue on a VM?

Comment: For mods, a batch-process is not the same of a SQL-batch. Batch-processing is not the correct tag!

Comment: Er. You have an auto log grow event that takes 116 seconds and you are asking why you get a 120 second delay? It will be blocked whilst the log is growing.

Comment: @MartinSmith No, actually it seems to happen even if the log is not grown.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into the exceution plan i think that the reason that the query sometimes takes longer is that the SQL server tries to cut some cornors using the statistics from the last query, but it backfires

I would say that it should be solved if you

1. Select the 3000 rows LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1 in a subquery first and join in the other data, or else the the server might consider some other table to be better, and then join that will all 80000 rows, and then filter it.
2. Skip the "not exists" clause and write it another way, like left outer join with the META_CELLS_UOM and only include the rows not matching. And also here do it as separate sub query to avoid bad optimization.

Try this (I dont know if I understand the relations right) and i might have missed a few tings, but I hope you understand.

```
INSERT INTO "LOAD"."META_CELLS_UOM" WITH (ROWLOCK) 
("UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOC_ID", "META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID")
```

SELECT "UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOC_ID", "META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID"
   FROM ( 
     SELECT "META_DOCUMENTS"."UDA_DOMAIN_ID", "META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID", "META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID", "META_SET_ID", "UDA_ID", "META_CELL_ROW" AS "META_CELL_UROW", "META_CELL_COL" AS "META_CELL_UCOL", "CEM_ID"
     FROM 
     ( 
        select * from "LOAD"."LOADER_CELLS_STEP_1" where ("META_CELL_WUOM"=1) AND ("UDA_TYPE"='MATCH')
     ) LCS
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_DOCUMENTS" ON ("META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_CODE"=LCS."META_DOC_CODE")
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_SECTIONS" ON ("META_SECTIONS"."META_DOC_ID"="META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID") AND ("META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_NAME"=LCS."META_SECT_NAME")
     INNER JOIN "LOAD"."META_SETS" ON ("META_SETS"."META_SECT_ID"="META_SECTIONS"."META_SECT_ID") AND ("META_SETS"."META_DOC_ID"="META_DOCUMENTS"."META_DOC_ID") AND ("META_SETS"."META_SET_NAME"=LCS."META_SET_NAME")

) "SELECTION"
   left outer join "LOAD"."META_CELLS_UOM" on ("SELECTION"."META_SET_ID"="META_CELLS_UOM"."META_SET_ID")  AND ("SELECTION"."UDA_ID"="META_CELLS_UOM"."UDA_ID")
   where "META_CELLS_UOM"."META_SET_ID" is null 
)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. Sorry for late answering, but I was on holiday.